# Error in a Link List

Tags: c++

I wrote the following code for a Link list to create a Book its serial no. and search it. I am using linked list in it.

When I add my first entry , it is added successfully, but when I add second entry it shows segmentation fault. I am not able to figure out why. Please help.
Thanks in advance.
Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct book
{
  int accno;
  string name;
  book* next;
};



int main()

{
  bool flag=false;
  int x,m;
  string s;
  book* front=NULL;
  book* n;
  do
    {

      cout<<"\nPlease select the following:\n1.Create and append\n2.Search\n3.Exit";
      cin>>m;
      switch(m)
    {
    case 1:
      n=new book();
      cout<<"\nEnter the book name: ";
      cin>>s;
      cout<<"\nEnter the acc no.: ";
      cin>>x;

      if(front==NULL)
        {
          front=n;
        }
      else
        {   n=front;

          while(n->next!=NULL)
        {
          n=n->next;
        }
          n=n->next;
        }

      n->accno=x;
      n->name=s;
      break;


    case 2:
      cout<<"Enter the roll no.";
      int y;
      cin>>y;
      if(front==NULL){cout<<"Doesnot exist\n"; break;
      }

      else
        {
          n=front;
          while(n->accno!=y && n->next!=NULL)
        {
          n->next=n;
        }
          cout<<"Book name is:"<<n->name;
          cout<<"\nAccno is: "<<n->accno;

        }
      break;


    case 3: flag=true;
      break;


    }
    }

  while(flag==false);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: is this homework? If it isn't use std::list instead of reimplementing that

Comment: "I wrote the following code for a Link list"? For why? You are `using namespace std`: there are plenty of suitable containers therein!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here

```
while(n->next!=NULL)
{
  n=n->next;
}
n=n->next;
```

you iterate through the linked list to find the last element, **then step past it**. After this, `n` will be `null`.

What you are missing is creating a new element and appending it to the end of the list.

And here

```
n->accno=x;
n->name=s;
```

you must also assign `n->next = null`, otherwise your list won't be properly terminated.

Also, when searching for a book, here

```
while(n->accno!=y && n->next!=NULL)
{
  n->next=n;
}
cout<<"Book name is:"<<n->name;
cout<<"\nAccno is: "<<n->accno;
```

after exiting the loop, either you found the book or `n` is `null`. You must check which is the case before trying to dereference n, otherwise you will again get a segfault if the book you are looking for is not in the list.

Comment: what are the remaining problems?

Comment: @Jan, Noone said it is - check my update. And if you see yet more problems, feel free to point them out in your own answer.

Comment: My major problem has been pointed out by viraj. As soon as I do n=front, I lose pointer to new node thats why when front!=null, I actually assign null values. Thanks guys

Comment: @Frustrated, that's only part of the problem. Even if you retained the original value of `n` (e.g. by using another pointer for traversing the list), you still need to append the new element to the list, as I noted above.

Answer (score 4):

1. Learn to write a linked list (so if this is a homework targeted at learning them, it's valid, but it is not tagged as such), but **never ever do it in practice**. There is a standard library and there is boost and they have all data structures you'll need unless you do something really special.
2. You have C++, so **don't write C-style code**. `book` should have a constructor that should initialize it's members. The list head should probably be encapsulated in the class too and manipulated using it's methods.
3. You never set n->next, so don't be surprised it never contains anything meaningful.
4. You re-use `n` in the loop forgetting the object you constructed (memory leak).
5. Than you get the NULL at the end of the list instead of the object you constructed.

Answer (score 1):

here lies your problem:

```
 ....
    else
    {   
        n=front;  

        while(n->next!=NULL)  //access to next will cause seg fault!!!
        {
              n=n->next;
        }
            n=n->next;  // step once more, now we have NULL on second add...
    }
```

also, where is `n->next` being assigned? I don't see it anywhere?

Comment: Besides repeating existing answer, that's not the only problem.

Comment: hey after i reach to the end of the list i do n=n->next which moves to the null entry . Now I set its accno and name

Comment: @Jan why don't you give us an answer, instead of mentioning "another problem" all the time...

Comment: @Frustrated: huh? why would you set the accno and name of a NULL entry? I'm not following

Comment: @Tony: I was composing it. It just took me a bit longer to mention all issues.

Comment: My major problem has been pointed out by viraj. As soon as I do n=front, I lose pointer to new node thats why when front!=null, I actually assign null values. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing here?

```
case 1:
    n=new book();
    cout<<"\nEnter the book name: ";
    cin>>s;
    cout<<"\nEnter the acc no.: ";
    cin>>x;
      if(front==NULL) 
     {
        front=n;
      } 
   else
      {   
         n=front;
    }
 while(n->next!=NULL)
      {
        n=n->next;
      } 
       n=n->next;
      }
      n->accno=x;
    n->name=s; 
   break;
```

You have created new book and assigned it to n, in first case its ok becasue your are directly assigning it to front. But in other case you should iterate list using someother variable (temp), when your write n = front, your have already lost your new book object pointer. Hope you got your answer.

Comment: so I should use temp to iterate to the end of linked list and then do temp=n?

Answer (score 1):

This is a buggy code:

1. You need null the "next" field when you add a new node:

   case 1:
   new book();
   n->next = NULL;
   ...
2. You have the memory leakage